# tags being ignored when using res() in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I couldn't find anything about this so I guess I will post it here. I am a newbie at node.js

I tried creating a button using node js with the following code:

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.end('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><body><button type="button">Click Me!</button></body></head></html>');
```

Yet when seen on the browser, it displays:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <body>
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
   </body>
  </head>
 </html>
```

as if the tags are completely ignored.

Inspecting the html source code, it looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap:break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <body>
   <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
  </body>
 </head>
</html>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Any Ideas why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have `text/plain` inside `response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});` you need to have **`text/html`**.

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
```

Using `text/plain` the response won't be parsed and you get what you give, plain text (or "tags are ignored").

Using `text/html` will tell the browser that this is HTML and it needs to be parsed.